# Does every harmonic function on $0 < |z - 1| < 1$ have a harmonic conjugate?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let$$D = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : 0 < |z - 1| < 1\}.$$Does every harmonic function on $D$ have a harmonic conjugate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. A counterexample would be the function $\log |x - 1|$. Note that the domain is *not* star-shaped.